# Why mixing two sines sounds like a triangle?

Tags: audio, audio-processing, music, signal-synthesis

I'm not sure where to post this question that is related to audio synthesis through programmation.

More specifically, I'm using a library called [synthplayer](https://github.com/irmen/synthesizer) that implement basic synthesizer in Python.

When trying to produce a "chord" effect i.e. playing two notes at the same time I experienced something unexpected: mixing the two sine waves corresponding to the notes result in a triangle-ish sound i.e. not "round" as a sine would be.

I use the following code whish is quite self explainatory without knowing the lib

```
from synthplayer.synth import WaveSynth
from synthplayer.playback import Output

synth_player = WaveSynth()


def sine(*args, **kwargs):
    return synth_player.sine(*args, **kwargs)


def get_sample():
    sine1 = sine(440, 2)
    sine2 = sine(220, 1)
    sine1.mix(sine2)
    return sine1


with Output(nchannels=1, mixing="sequential", queue_size=2) as out:
    out.play_sample(get_sample())
    out.wait_all_played()
```

You can hear it: http://sndup.net/hvz8

Does anyone has an idea of what's going on?

Comment: Only on mobile right now, but look into fourier series. In particular into the fourier series of triangle waves.

Comment: That really depends a lot what exactly the method `mix()` is doing. Does it sum, average, multiply or do something else ? Can you post an (accessible) link to the documentation?

Answer (score 4):

I tried looking at what your libraries output as just a sine wave by modifying your code:

```
def get_sample():
    sine1 = sine(440, 2)
    # sine2 = sine(220, 1)
    # sine1.mix(sine2)
    return sine1
```

and then plotting the resulting data:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
def twos_comp(val, bits):
    """compute the 2's complement of int value val"""
    if (val & (1 << (bits - 1))) != 0: # if sign bit is set e.g., 8bit: 128-255
        val = val - (1 << bits)        # compute negative value
    return val                         # return positive value as is

N = 400

int_values = [twos_comp(x,8) for x in get_sample()._Sample__frames]
plt.plot(int_values[0:N])
plt.xlim([0,N])
```

and got something that doesn't look like a clean sinewave:

[image: Plot of sine wave]

I wonder if the library is doing the right thing?

I made a modification to my code:

```
plt.plot(int_values[1:N:2])
```

and that produces something more sensible:

[image: Single channel plot]

So it looks like `sine()` is producing a stereo signal (or perhaps a 16 bit signal?).

Uncommenting the `sine2` and `mix` lines of your `get_sample` shows more problems:

[image]

So perhaps your code needs to scale them before mixing?

If I change your `get_sample` to:

```
def get_sample():
    sine1 = sine(440, 2, amplitude=0.4)
    sine2 = sine(220, 1, amplitude=0.4) 
    sine1.mix(sine2)
    return sine1
```

which changes the sine amplitudes, then I get

[image: This might work]

Answer (score 1):

See the plot below of what adding two sinusoids together that are harmonically related (specifically the second as twice the frequency of the first) but of equal amplitude and same initial phase would look like (in this case a cosine added to a cosine at twice the frequency):

[image: adding sinusoids]

And another case, with a different phase between the two (in this case a cosine was added to a sine):

[image: adding sinusoids]

Answer (score 1):

This is your ear and brain playing "tricks" on you.  It's just a (psycho-acoustically experimentally verified) fact that the human ear and brain combine simultaneous exactly (or very nearly exactly) harmonically related frequency separate sinusoids or sinusoidal components (from the same direction, starting at the same time, etc.) into the perception of a single pitched sound; and combines the number and relative amplitudes of those sinusoidal overtones into different sensations of Timbre.